# Tightvnc server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc, tightvnc

I have a VM in which I installed the VNC server (TightVNC) using the link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04

It is installed successfully and I can see the port 5901 running

```
/etc/tigervnc$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16460/Xtigervnc     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5902          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16183/Xtigervnc     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5901                :::*                    LISTEN      16460/Xtigervnc     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5902                :::*                    LISTEN      16183/Xtigervnc     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36618           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp    29184      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp     7680      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::37372                :::*                                -                   
udp6   20736      0 :::5353                 :::*
```

Now from my local machine, I tried to do the port binding to my local from VM (as per the link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -C -N -l test 172.1.1.1
```

In my local machine, I able to see the port is binded to 5901

```
/etc/guacamole$ fuser 5901/tcp
5901/tcp:            22049
```

Now when I try to take the VNC connection using 127.0.0.1:5901, It promopts for VM's password and shows only the blank page.

[image]

Comment: Does your VM software provide a screen view, like e.g. VirtualBox, so that you can check, if your VM provides a "desktop" at all?

Comment: In particular, the guide you linked includes a step of editing the `.vnc/xstartup` file to invoke `startxfce4` - are the relevant XFCE4 packages actually installed?

Comment: @Marvin, I created this VM using ovirt and it is able to provide the desktop version of VM

Comment: Since you can connect the VNC, does it respond to keyboard input at all?  I have seen VNC displays "sleep" after an amount of inactivity and just hitting enter (or any key really) brings the display back up.

Comment: @GracefulRestart It is working finally, using the following configuration

xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
startxfce4 &

Also start the vncserver : env -u SESSION_MANAGER -u DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS vncserver